# How to resolve session not created exception for iphone devices

Tags: java, ios, windows, appium

I am using appium studio on windows to automate an app on iPhone.
When I am using bundle id its not working but when I am giving the app location xpath and clicking on it, it is launching the application.
Please help me to launch the application using bundle id.

```
             DesiredCapabilities dCapabilities=new DesiredCapabilities();                      
                    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub");           
                  dCapabilities.setCapability("reportDirectory","report");
        dCapabilities.setCapability("fullReset", false);            
        dCapabilities.setCapability("reportFormat", "xml");
        dCapabilities.setCapability("testName", "SampleTest");               

        dCapabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BUNDLE_ID,"au.com.chat.chatapp");
        dCapabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.LOCATION_SERVICES_AUTHORIZED,"true");
         dCapabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "00008020-00065C813E12002E");
      driver = new IOSDriver<MobileElement>(url,dCapabilities);
```

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create a new remote session. Please check the server log for more details. Original error: session not created (An unknown server-side error occurred. status='false'. Failed to complete internal method: 'launch args: [au.com.chat.chatapp, false, true]', details: Failed to launch activity / URL. The application: au.com.chat.chatapp is not installed on the device (reportUrl=C:\Users\system name\appiumstudio-reports\report\test25))  (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 6.67 seconds
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: '10263TAB', ip: '10.10.32.60', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_221'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Answer (score 0):

It worked, I corrected the bundle id .